# What does set `:rbenv_roles, :all` means in capistrano deploy.rb?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, rbenv

I just set `set :rbenv_roles, :all # default value` as the instruction says.

https://github.com/capistrano/rbenv/

But I don't know what the `rbenv_roles` means. In which situation I should change the value and how it effect the environments?

Comment: I think it means to use rbenv on all the roles you have configured.  If you only have a single server doing all your roles (web/app/db) then I can see where I might not make sense.  But if your deployment has multiple servers each doing different roles you might not use rbenv on all of them.

Comment: I got it thanks! As you expected I'm using a single server so that I don't need to change it.